# How to check whether a string array has a newline or not in C++?

Tags: c++, string

```
  #include<sstream>
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main(){
     string line = "test one two three. \n another one \n";
     string arr[8];
     cout<<line;
     int i = 0;
     stringstream ssin(line);
     while (ssin.good() && i < 8){
         ssin >> arr[i];
         ++i;
     }
     for(i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        cout << arr[i];
     } 
  return 0; 
  }
```

//Now i want to print that elements that just come before the newline ("\n") in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think of `"test one two three. \n another one \n"` as one line of text. It is not. It is two lines of text.

You need to change your strategy of reading a little bit.

```
int main()
{
   string input = "test one two three. \n another one \n";
   string arr[8];
   int i = 0;

   stringstream ssin_1(input);
   string line;

   // Read only the tokens from the first line.
   if ( std::getline(ssin_1, line) )
   {
      stringstream ssin_2(line);
      while ( ssin_2 >> arr[i] && i < 8)
      {
         ++i;
      }
   }

   // Don't print all the elements of arr
   // Print only what has been read.
   for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
      cout << arr[j] << " ";
   } 

   return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ssin >> arr[i]` skips whitespace, losing all knowledge of which `arr` entries were followed by newlines.

Instead, you can divide input into lines first, then words, while tracking the newlines:

```
std::vector<size_t> newline_after_word_index;
std::vector<std::string> words;
while (getline(ssin, line))
{
    std::istringstream line_ss(line);
    std::string word;
    while (line_ss >> word)
        words.push_back(word);
    newline_after_word_index.push_back(words.size());
}
```

You can then use indices from `newline_after_word_index` to print out the `words[]` entry beforehand....

Comment: actually i have no idea of vector can you implement it in my program. If possible. Thank you

Comment: @DineshKumar All you need to do to use `std::vector` in your program is `#include <vector>` at the top.  A `std::vector` is much like the array you used, but it can size itself - just `push_back()` new items to the end and it'll get more memory if it needs it.  You can still use `words[i]` to access the elements just like your array.  (You should get a good introductory C++ book).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

```
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string line = "test one two three. \n another one \n";
    size_t found = line.find("\n");
    for (int i=0; i<=found; i++){
      cout << line[i];
    }
return 0; }
```